# Is there any way to extract child models from 3d model binary file with python

Tags: modeling, python, scripting, import

I'm gonna Update my Question.

I have the models of an old game that are serialised in to binary files.Game serialised bunch of SO1 files from the source code into single binary file to make a complete model with child models(like collision mesh for physics and debris mesh for when for example the model destroyed or something). And then we have script to import these binaries into blender.

But the problem is that script only read the basic mesh of these serialised binaries.It does not extract other mesh like debris.So what I want to do is to write a script to extract all the meshes from the serialised models and import into Blender. Is there any way to extract the child models from the model like different meshes or stuff. Is there any resources that you can share or any tip that might help.

### **Update**

[Here is the sample of the serialised model](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cL1UE1GuhtzfXt74UZOr09bykSK60jBL)

Any kind of resources or tip would be really help.
Thanks

Comment: What is the "ASCII" format. Can you link to a file specification?

Comment: HI leander! Thanks for the reply. ASCII fbx format i could be wrong is that  the models are in human readable files that need to be imported in blender. I can show you the file tho. The file format is .S01. we can open in notepad and can see all the coordinates and other info.

Comment: Updated my question with the link.Hopw you can guide me. Thanks

Comment: I understand your question now. Have you tried the [fbx converter](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-converter-archives)?

Comment: That's the confusion Because i need to do with script but i don't know how to approach with it exactly. Like first i need to convert then write a script to import or is there any way i can do with programming.